# Using ODP.NET OracleAQQueue.Listen on a Multiconsumer Queue

Tags: oracle, odp.net, oracle-aq

I have a client app that connects to an Oracle AQ multi-consumer queue.  I want to use OracleAQQueue.Listen to listen for new messages on the queue.  [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E18754_01/OracleAQQueueClass.htm#CHDBFFIG) show that the Listen method can be used for multi-consumer queues.  My code for listening to the queue is shown below.

```
string consumerName = "APPINST1";            
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    OracleAQQueue queue = new OracleAQQueue("MY_Q");
    queue.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;
    queue.UdtTypeName = "MY_Q_MSG";
    queue.DequeueOptions.DeliveryMode = OracleAQMessageDeliveryMode.Persistent;
    queue.Connection = con;

    Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages...");
    queue.Listen(new string[] { consumerName });
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that on the line of code where I call queue.Listen(), I get the Oracle exception:

```
ORA-25295: Subscriber is not allowed to dequeue buffered messages
```

Googling for advice on this particular error hasn't been too helpful.  I've removed and re-added my subscriber to the queue several times to no avail.  My guess is that I'm not setting some property correctly before I make the call to Listen, but I can't figure out the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across the following note in the Streams Advanced Queuing User's Guide, in [Chapter 10 - Oracle Streams AQ Operations Using PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/aq_opers.htm#CIHDAEEG):

```
Note: Listening to multiconsumer queues is not supported in the Java API.
```

Although I can't find it explicitly stated anywhere, I'm guessing the same rule applies to the ODP.NET API.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the visibility attribute to IMMEDIATE to use buffered messaging.